# how to increase Apache 2 uri length limit

Tags: apache2

I am getting this error in my apache2 log:

> [Tue Apr 06 09:00:56 2010] [error] [client A.B.C.D] request failed:
>   URI too long (longer than 8190)

What setting can I change to increase this limit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You would have to set `DEFAULT_LIMIT_REQUEST_LINE` constant inside of the Apache source code, and recompile Apache. This constant is in the `httpd.h` header file.

After this is done you can decrease request limit using the `LimitRequestLine` directive.

See the http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestline for more info.

Comment: NB: This is only true in Apache 2.0 and earlier. Apache 2.2 and later (i.e, all modern versions of Apache) do not require code changes to increase `LimitRequestLine`.

Answer (score 17):

The best answer is "don't do that". See [https://boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20190902193246/https://boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html) (link goes to Internet Archive backup) for an explanation of why.

If you need to pass that much data, use POST, not GET.

Comment: Yep, best answer. However, it's not possible to do that if you are trying to pass POST data to a URL that is expecting a form token.

Comment: doesn't apply to OSRM

Answer (score 14):

Open `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

and insert under `AccessFileName .htaccess`:

```
LimitRequestLine 1000000
LimitRequestFieldSize 1000000
```

Comment: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 8):

A quick hack to get it working you just edit the apache2.conf file and add the line:

```
LimitRequestLine 100000
```

Restart apache and you are all good. Although you should change the code to use POST instead of GET and remove the line as soon as you can.

Comment: where is that??

Comment: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Answer (score 5):

I you use virtual hosts with Apache, you have to set `LimitRequestLine` and `LimitRequestFieldSize` within the first virtual host definition with a matching port.
For Ubuntu/Debian this is in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`.

It doesn't work if you set these parameters in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

Comment: The only way I could get this to work was to insert into /etc/apache2/ports.conf 

# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443

LimitRequestLine 1000000
LimitRequestFieldSize 1000000

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

other wise it was ignored

Answer (score 0):

Increase the Apache limits for [limit request line](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline) and [limit request field size](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestfieldsize) and save it.

Next step, Restart apache using `sudo service apache2 restart`

Hope, this will solve the problem.