# PHP - too many characters in textarea

Tags: php

I have a problem with textarea - when I paste more than 65000 characters and I try to print this `$_POST['value']` on screen - I get `"NULL"` - `$_POST['value']` doesn't exist. When I paste ~55000 characters - everything is OK and I can see the characters when I try to print this POST array.

Why I can't paste more than ~65000 characters? When I try do it on another web server - everything is OK, so I think I have some limit, but where and how I can manage this limit ?

Comment: Check your webserver config - dependent on which you use you need to change the maximum body size. [You also need to make sure that `max_post_size` is a decent value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2364875/247893).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to increase apache 2 uri length limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586339/how-to-increase-apache-2-uri-length-limit)

Comment: OK, so what I should add to .htaccess if I would like to add 100.000 characters in textarea ?

Comment: @Dinidu method is `POST`, so URI length doesn't matter.

Comment: @Dinidu POST is not sent in the URL, so it's not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/post-max-size). In your `.htaccess` file, add the following:

```
php_value post_max_size 20M
```

This will allow the data sent with at `POST` request to be up to 20 MB (megabytes).

Comment: @Majkson try `ini_set('post_max_size', '60M');` in php code. (change value as required)

Comment: @Majkson and also there is `memory_limit` you can try to change similarly.

Comment: I added this in PHP file but it still doesn't work. Can you tell me how I can change this memory_limit ??