# Making HTTP POST request using requests in Python

Tags: python, api, http, post

I am trying to make a HTTP request to an API using the POST method. The API that I am using is meant to take in three parameters (key1, key2, key3) and return a json file. Unfortunately, my POST request does not seem to return anything when I am using the **data** method to pass my dictionary to the API. This seems to be very strange because it seems to work when I am using the **params** method. I cannot try to understand this as this process seems to be very opaque (e.g. I cannot a URL to see how the payload are passed onto the API).

My question: What am I doing wrong here?

POST request where the parameters are sent over to the API using **data** method:

```
import requests

url = 'http://example.com/API.php'
payload =  {
            'key1': '<<Contains very long json string>>', 
            'key2': 5, 
            'key3': 0
           }

print len(str(payload)) # Prints 6717
r = requests.post(url, data=payload) << Note data is used here
print r.status_code # Prints 200
print r.text # Prints empty string
```

POST request code where the parameters are sent over to the API using the **params** method:

```
import requests

url = 'http://example.com/API.php'
payload =  {
            'key1': '<<Contains very long json string>>', 
            'key2': 5, 
            'key3': 0
           }

print len(str(payload)) # Prints 6717
r = requests.post(url, params=payload) << Note here params is used here
print r.status_code # Prints 200
print r.text # Prints expected JSON results
```

If you are wondering why I would like to use the **data** method over **params**... I am trying to pass other dictionaries containing longer strings and the **params** method does not seem to do it because I am getting *ERROR 414*. I was hoping that the error could be resolved by using **data**.

The API that I am using was written in PHP.

Comment: What encoding does the API expect for the request body? Could it be expecting JSON, or multipart/form-data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "data" and "params" in Python requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535920/difference-between-data-and-params-in-python-requests)

Comment: I am sorry. At the moment, I am not entirely sure about this as the API was written in PHP by my colleague. However, I was going under the assumption that the API was expecting a JSON. I have tried the adding the following headers to the HTTP request along with the **data** method:
`headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}` and
`headers = {'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8"}` They didn't seem to help. I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**
This is because params sends the parameters as part of the http POST request, while data sends them as part of the body of the request. In your case: just call the api using params and you're fine. This is absolutely normal (and expected) behaviour.

**Demonstration**
Just start two commandlines. On the first, run netcat: `nc -l 8888`. On the other commandline, run python:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.post('http://localhost:8888',data={'a':1,'b':'2'})
```

At the netcat-side, we see the following request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.18.1
Content-Length: 7
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

a=1&b=2
```

Next, try the params way:

```
>>> requests.post('http://localhost:8888',params={'a':1,'b':'2'})
```

Netcat reports:

```
POST /?a=1&b=2 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.18.1
Content-Length: 0
```

Note the differences in the first and last line.

As you can read from the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#main-interface) (italic emphasis is mine):

> **params** -- (optional) Dictionary or bytes to be sent *in the query string* for the Request.
>   **data** -- (optional) Dictionary or list of tuples [(key, value)] (will be form-encoded), bytes, or file-like object to send *in the body* of the Request.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the difference between **params** and **data**. I do not understand why sending my dictionary over to the API as part of the body does not return anything while sending it part of the HTTP request works. Do you think it could be a problem arising on the API side?

Comment: No. This is perfectly normal behaviour in such cases. The (http server of the) API just looks at the posted url and extracts the parameters from there. It probably ignores the content (data) of the post. Posts with data are common when uploading forms with files. The form is sent like with "params". The file is send using "data".

Comment: Just use params when calling your API. I'll add this to my answer, because that answers that last bit of your question

Comment: I am working with multiple dictionaries, with each one representing a document. I am sending each dictionary to the API to process some information about the document and return results. Using **params** works for some dictionaries and doesn't work for others. For example, for a document `print len(str(payload))` prints 18563 - this is clearly a **very large dictionary**. As you can expect, trying to make the HTTP request using *params* throws back the following error: 414 Request-URI Too Large - The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.

Comment: In that case, you should see what other option this API has. [RFC 2616](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html) states that there is no a-priori restriction on uri length, so it depends on the webserver you hare talking to. 8KB (8192 bytes) is a common limit. Anything beyond that size should be handled differently than putting all that document data inside the uri. Without more context, all I can suggest is to check the documentation of the API.

Comment: The problems that I have been experiencing seems to be consistent with your last hypothesis. Anything below 8000 characters (or ~8KB) seems to be fine and anything beyond that, I seem to be experiencing error 414. Since the API is hosted on a webserver that I have control over, would it be possible to increase the 8KB? I am aware that this is not a bad practice. However, at this stage I am testing whether my script works as expected.

Comment: That question [already has an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586339/how-to-increase-apache-2-uri-length-limit) on Stack Overflow.