# Wordpress gutenberg custom block — issues with preview loading

Tags: ajax, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I created a plugin with custom blocks. I am have trouble with the block preview. When I set the block on preview mode and reload the page editor — I get a error message on all the blocks I've preview `Error loading block: You are probably offline.`

In the console I am also getting the following errors:

```
pd-admin.js?ver=2.20:12 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).live is not a function
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.5:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of undefined
```

Any ideas what I am doing to cause this?

I find issue with the `RichText` field — if the `RichText` is too long I can't preview the block at all and in the block I get the same error message saying `Error loading block: You are probably offline.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix console error : WordPress 5.5 stopped using jQuery migrate. This change has been causing problems with old plugins and themes. If you are noticing issues after upgrading to WordPress 5.5, installing this plugin might fix it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate-helper/

For `RichText` long text error, you need to increase `LimitRequestLine` in your apache configuration. Ref : [how to increase Apache 2 uri length limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586339/how-to-increase-apache-2-uri-length-limit)